# How do I remove float object in dataframe? Ex: "winter 2021" to "winter"

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

I have the premiered column where I want to remove the year and only keep the season. Example: "winter 2021" to become "winter" .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
Regular expression `to_replace`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['bat', 'foo', 'bait'],
                   'B': ['abc', 'bar', 'xyz']})
df.replace(to_replace=r'^ba.$', value='new', regex=True)

...
        A    B
0   new  abc
1   foo  new
2  bait  xyz
```

In your case it will be:

```
df.replace(to_replace=r'^Fa.$', value='Fall', regex=True)
...
...
```

For future,  I suggest refer here about regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Note:
^
(Caret.) Matches the start of the string, and in MULTILINE mode also matches immediately after each newline.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

this will remove all digits in the column